# How do I update rows in one table based on data not being present in another table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I need to update records in one table based on records in another table being either missing or having a logically deleted flag.

I have three tables: Items, Customers, and Pricing. Pricing links to both ItemID and CustomerID. Items and Customers records get logically deleted from an external source (and then physically deleted later).  Pricing does when the records change, but not when Items or Customers record get deleted.

I can use a left outer join to identify records in Pricing that should be logically deleted, but I can't figure out how to update based on the join. I tried based on a question I found here,

This works, and displays records for which either the Items record no longer exists or the Items record is marked logically deleted.

```
SELECT p.ItemKey FROM Pricing AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items as i
on p.ItemKey = i.ItemID 
WHERE i.ItemID IS NULL OR i.deleted = 'Y'
```

This marks all the records deleted, not just the ones that were found in the previous query.

```
UPDATE Pricing SET deleted = 'Y' WHERE ItemKey IN 
(SELECT p.ItemKey FROM Pricing AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items as i
on p.ItemKey = i.ItemID 
WHERE i.ItemID IS NULL OR i.deleted = 'Y')
```

The same issue happens with Customers and CustomerID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT p.* FROM Pricing AS p 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Items as i
    on p.ItemKey = i.ItemID 
  WHERE i.ItemID IS NULL OR i.deleted = 'Y'
)
UPDATE cte
SET deleted = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE p SET p.deleted = 'Y'
FROM Pricing AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items AS i
on p.ItemKey = i.ItemID 
WHERE i.ItemID IS NULL OR i.deleted = 'Y'
```